# How can I chain many sequential promises while limiting stack depth?

Tags: javascript, promise, stack-overflow

I am trying to send out network data. Essentially, the library I am using has a 16kb limit on message size, so I must break down larger messages and send them in chunks. A really simplified version of my code might look like:

```
function sendInChunks(buffers) {
    send(buffers.shift()).then(sendInChunks.bind(undefined, buffers));
}
```

With a recursive implementation like this, the amount of data I can send is limited by the stack depth limits of whatever platform the code is running on. I was wondering if there is a way to send my data without the limitation of stack depth?

Note: In the actual implementation I have right now, I am actually using mutual recursion to do some checks after calling send. There is also some state from a higher scope used in both functions, but hopefully that wont change much.

EDIT: I am using es6 promises.

Comment: Can you clarify which implementation of ES6 Promises you are using? If this pattern is limited by stack depth, there is a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promises are asynchronous, which means it's not actually recursive calls; it's more like a loop.  A simple example of this is the following, which isn't recursive either.

```
function send(buffers){
    buffers.shift();
    if (buffers.length) {
        setTimeout(send.bind(null, buffers), 10);
    }
}

send(buffers);
```

When we call `send`, it shifts a buffer, and then maybe registers a timeout, and then returns.  Because it returns without calling itself, it's not recursive.

<sub>side note: With ES6, there's proper tail call optimization; which means recursion limits won't be a problem as often.</sub>

Comment: Excellent! Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: It's a combination of several things, as well as common promise implementations; the ES6 spec draft; and Promises/A+.  I'd have to dig through all of them to find exact quotes.  A little reading between the lines is also required.

Answer (score 1):

> the amount of data I can send is limited by the stack depth limits of whatever platform the code is running on

No. Since Promises are resolved asynchronously, a new stack frame will be used for each callback, and you won't run into a stack overflow.